# Return value of function gets ignored

Tags: python-3.x

```
VOWELS = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

BEGINNING = ["th", "st", "qu", "pl", "tr"]


def pig_latin2(word):
    # word is a string to convert to pig-latin
    string = word
    string = string.lower()
    # get first letter in string
    test = string[0]
    if test not in VOWELS:
        # remove first letter from string skip index 0
        string = string[1:] + string[0]
        # add characters to string
        string = string + "ay"
    if test in VOWELS:
        string = string + "hay"
    print(string)


def pig_latin(word):
    string = word
    transfer_word = word
    string.lower()
    test = string[0] + string[1]
    if test not in BEGINNING:
        pig_latin2(transfer_word)

    if test in BEGINNING:
        string = string[2:] + string[0] + string[1] + "ay"
    print(string)
```

When I un-comment the code below and replace print(string) with return string in above two functions, it only works for words in pig_latin(). As soon as word should be passed to pig_latin2() I get a value of None for all words and the programs crashes.

```
# def start_program():
    # print("Would you like to convert words or sentence into pig latin?")
    # answer = input("(y/n) >>>")
    # print("Only have words with spaces, no punctuation marks!")
    # word_list = ""
    # if answer == "y":
    #   words = input("Provide words or sentence here: \n>>>")
    #   new_words = words.split()
    #   for word in new_words:
    #       word = pig_latin(word)
    #       word_list = word_list + " " + word
    #   print(word_list)

    # elif answer == "n":
    #   print("Goodbye")
    #   quit()


    # start_program()
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in debug mode? That should help you find and fix the error yourself.

Comment: I am struggling to make sense of debugger will try too work it out.

Comment: if i input: play stone quit, ie any word that will match BEGINNINGS my program works.  If I input: image away, ie any word that will need pig_latin2() I get a return of None. Yet I have told python to return string.  DEBUGGER: word = {NoneType}None

Comment: What are your inputs? It doesn't return None when I try an input like "Python is awesome".

Comment: >>>image away
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ruark/IdeaProjects/MIT Course/pig_latin.py", line 72, in <module>
    start_program()
  File "C:/Users/ruark/IdeaProjects/MIT Course/pig_latin.py", line 64, in start_program
    word_list = word_list + " " + word
TypeError: must be str, not NoneType

Comment: Try to use `start_program word_list = str(word_list) + " " + str(word)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not capturing the return value of the `pig_latin2` function. So whatever that function does, you're discarding its output.

Fix this line in the `pig_latin` function:

```
if test not in BEGINNING:
    string = pig_latin2(transfer_word)  # <----------- forgot 'string =' here
```

When fixed thusly, it works for me. Having said that, there would still be a bunch of stuff to clean up.

Comment: Yes. Also, `string.lower()` doesn't affect without assigning.